# Can't use paginate after using switch. - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-paginate

I want to use the switch before using paginate. But am getting this error in my view -

***Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::links()***.

My Code -
MyController.php

```php
$var = User::select('somefield', 'anotherfield');

switch($condition){
   case foo:
       $var->where('bar', '=', 'xyz');
   break;
   case etc:
       $var->where('bar', '=', 'abc')
   break;
}
$var->paginate(10);
return View::make('x.y.z', compact('var'));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to catch in some variable as,

```
$data = $var->paginate(10);
return View::make('x.y.z', compact('data'));
```

In your current code, you are not saving paginated result anywhere.